# OpenLDAP How to give sudo access to a limited set of machiines only

Tags: ldap, sudo

I am trying to setup an LDAP server for multiple machines. I want to have an account which only has sudo access in a some machines, not all. Will having a multi-valued sudoHost in a SudoRole solve this? If not are there any other ways to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said yourself, a multivalued `sudoHost` attribute will do the job. If you set it to 'ALL', the rule will be valid an all hosts on which sudo reads that LDAP subtree.